# Scrollable background image in CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I have looked all over the internet and I still can't find the solution to this question. How would I make a background image in my website that scales to fit the whole display but it scrolls away with the page when you scroll down to view the rest of the webpage content in CSS. I also want text that will be over the image. ex. my name and a picture of me.

Comment: I guessing that your background is longer than the webpage, so set the width:100%; and aslong as the background is longer then the image with fit the whole screen and still scroll.

Comment: Try this https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

Comment: `background-size:100%` although when the window is resized it can look bad.

Comment: wait, you mean something like https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/p29zpm67 In a full-screen enviroment, it fills up the screen

Answer (score 1):

The `background-attachment` CSS property is what you want. set `background-attachment` to `local.` That makes it scroll along with its contents!